# Rails Web App Architecture in Heroku

Tags: heroku, webserver, n-tier-architecture, appserver

Is it possible to configure multiple web-server to an app-server in heroku? Playing with heroku, I don't see that is possible. Heroku deployment as I understand doesn't support web and app server separation. Just wanted to double check my understanding.

Appreciate your thoughts on this!

Answer (score 0):

Heroku as things stand today, does not have a web-server option. You got to keep this in mind for some of your app configurations like cacheing, response compressing etc.

In the case of rails or node platforms, you got to set app-level configurations or have middlewares to take care of these kind of things.